# ping works but not ssh?

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, networking, ping

- I connected two linuxes (CentOS7) with an ethernet cable, and
- I did `ifconfig <eth> 192.168.0.1` on the first and `.. 0.2` on the second.
- From the second, `ping 192.168.0.1` works, but
- `ssh <mylogin_on_first>@192.168.0.1` does nothing (ends by an timeout)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ping uses the icmp protocol, which doesn't require a port.

ssh nee to be open on the machine to which you're attempting to connect, and an ssh daemon running.

To check the port is open on 'the first' machine, 192.168.0.1 :

```
 $ sudo firewall-cmd --list-services
   dhcpv6-client ssh samba-client
```

ssh should be listed as above. To check if the ssh daemon is running (on 'the first'):

```
 $ sudo systemctl status sshd
   sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
  oaded (/usr/listemd/system/sshd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (runnST; 1s ago
   ...
```

It should be 'Active' as above.

Then, if needed, to open the port:

```
 $ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http
success
 $ swall-cmd --reload
success
```

And to start the service:

```
$ sudo systemctl start sshd
```